# How to disable showing visibility symbols in Tagbar for a specific filetype?

Tags: python, vim, tags, tagbar

I want [`g:tagbar_show_visibility`](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar/blob/master/doc/tagbar.txt) be set to `'0'` for Python files as there's no public/protected/private in Python. How can I configure Vim this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize `ctagsargs` for a particular filetype, making `ctags` not output the 'visibility' information for tags in the first place, e.g.:

```
let g:tagbar_type_python = {
    \ 'ctagsargs' : '-f - --excmd=pattern --fields=nksSmt'
\ }
```

The important bit here is the `--fields` option, which specifies the fields to be included for each tag.

Answer (score 1):

To perform the operation manually execute this:

```
:TagbarClose
:let g:tagbar_show_visibility = 0
:TagbarOpen
```

you can add the following line to your vimrc to make it automatically:

```
au BufRead *.py :let g:tagbar_show_visibility = 0
```

The autocommand (au) execute a command on specific events. With this particular example it sets the variable to 0 for buffers .py at the moment vim read them.

**EDIT**

My solution does not work very well. Since the variable g:tagbar_show_bisibility is global. The Tagbar plugin seems to read it when TagbarOpen is called. So a better approach will be to use a function to open Tagbar, say TagbarOpen2 or something. The function would check the filetype of the current buffer and set the visibility variable accordingly.

**EDIT2**

I made a script that will set the visibility each time you enter a buffer. Then to refresh the Tagbar I use TagbarToggle two time in a row. It is a little anoying, but its the best I got. Maybe you could come up with something better avoiding the flikering if you spend some time.

Please share if improve this script.

```
function! TagbarUpdate()
    if (&ft == 'tagbar')
        return
    endif
    let g:tagbar_show_visibility = 1
    if (&ft == 'python')
        let g:tagbar_show_visibility = 0
    endif
    exec ":TagbarToggle"
    exec ":TagbarToggle"
endfunction

au! BufEnter * :call TagbarUpdate()
```